# How to shuffle a .jpg image's pixels by rows using PIL and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I want to reorder pixels in `.jpg` image by rows. Using various answers that I found in the internet, I wrote:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

a = Image.open('donkey.jpg')
b = a.getdata()
b = np.reshape(b, (a.height, a.width, 3))

dic = []
for i in range(1, a.height):
    element = np.reshape(b[:i], (i * a.width, 3))
    dic.append(element)
```

`dic` produces something likes this:

```
[array([[205, 225, 232],
        [201, 222, 227],
        [203, 224, 227],
        ...,
        [204, 222, 224],
        [210, 226, 225],
        [230, 222, 186]]),
 array([[205, 225, 232],
        [201, 222, 227],
        [203, 224, 227],
        ...,
        [188, 183, 154],
        [180, 175, 146],
        [181, 175, 143]]),

        ...,

 array([[205, 225, 232],
        [201, 222, 227],
        [203, 224, 227],
        ...,
        [249, 251, 240],
        [249, 251, 240],
        [249, 249, 241]])]
```

I think I was successful at shuffling the image's pixels by rows. But, I am having trouble converting it back to an image.

I tried:

```
Image.fromarray(dic.astype)
```

Which, did not work. Here is the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

Please help me convert the shuffled image back to image!

Comment: It's because you tried to call an attribute `astype` from a list(`[]`). Have you tried  `Image.fromarray(np.array(dic))`?

Comment: I get the following error message using that method: ``TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1), |O``

Comment: I believe the data causes this error. You should be able to suppress this error with `Image.fromarray(np.array(dic).astype(np.uint8))`

Comment: Hm. Please forgive my noobness. I'm still learning python. I get this error message now. ``ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.``

Comment: Please, there is no such thing. We are here either to learn or help.(Most often both! :)) This error's cause is that the elements in `dic` do not match in size. And that is caused by `i * a.width` in `np.reshape(b[:i], (i * a.width, 3))`. As `i` gets larger, the width also gets larger, causing the rows' shape to mismatch.

Comment: Also, constant reshaping can mess up with the data you have, causing transmission between channels. What you might want to do is to split channels by `r`,`g`,`b` and use shuffle the rows by `np.random.permutation` and then concatanate the `rgb` channels after.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will work on my looping and understanding channels.

Comment: Let me get you a simple example to get you started. I will post a working example as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you're trying with the code below. It is a bit more complex to comprehend when you're a novice, but will do much when you get the hang of it.

The reasons for reformats;

- completely eliminated row-wise operations: decreases efficiency significantly. using `np.random.permutation` is a much faster and efficient approach.
- split the image into channels: avoiding the data transmission between channels when doing reshapes.
- using `dstack` to keep order of the channels and not mess up with the data while reshaping
- added `channel_count` to be able to process png or greyscale photos also, making the code snippet more foolproof.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("donkey.jpg")

# getting the number of channels
channel_count = len(img.getbands())

img_arr = np.reshape(img, (img.height, img.width, channel_count))

# splitting up channels
channels = [img_arr[:,:,x] for x in range(channel_count)]

# setting up a shuffling order for rows
random_perm = np.random.permutation(img.height)

# reordering the rows with respect to the permutation
shuffled_img_arr = np.dstack([x[random_perm, :] for x in channels]).astype(np.uint8)

# creating the Image from the shuffled array
shuffled_img = Image.fromarray(shuffled_img_arr)

# saving the shuffled file
shuffled_img.save("shuffled_donkey.jpg")
```

This code will save the image you give completely shuffled in rows.

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't work quite, but it gives me a great starting point. I appreciate your time very much.